# How to replace @max: function in NSPredicate, for Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

I have a Core Data model where Session has relationship to Activity which has timestamp property. Session are part of a Group, like this:

```
A-> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
B1  X 1 1 1 X 1 1 1 1
B2  X X Y 2 X 2 2 2 2
B3  3 X 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

So, here Groups are A1, A2 etc, Session is A1B1, A1B2 etc. This number after A is group.order, number after B is session.order (in the data model).
I marked Sessions with completed Activity using X and last such session marked with Y (A3B2).

It's obvious that session can be done as customer wants, no order is mandatory. What I need is a predicate that will give me the next session after the last completed one. In the example above, that would be A3B3.

I tried this, but it does not work with Core Data (unsupported aggregate function...)

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"activity = nil AND 
   group.order >= activity.timestamp.@max.session.group.order AND
   order > activity.timestamp.@max.session.order"]
```

I'm actually not sure it's the correct predicate, but never mind, it crashes because of @max so did not dwell on it much. I'm trying to figure out how to do this with SUBQUERY, but no luck.